What can trigger MS Access autoexec vba macro?
I have this ms access database (.mdb) which contains an autoexec macro that runs a vba sub.  It works, but I have a group full of users who are all saying they never open the .mdb file.  There are DSNs that point to it.  So when else can autoexec run (besides a user manually opening the mdb)?

Are there ways that the MDB is automatically opened? Logon script? batch file?  You can open the MDB with the shift key held down to skip the autoexec. Once it is open you can manually execute the autoexec whenever you want just like any other macro.

Are you saying that the macro is running when it should not?  It's not clear if you have a problem, or are just asking a question.

If your autoexec is quick and it contains application.quit then your users could be running the MDB without realizing it. It could be opened via a logon script or batch file and closed after opening and running the macro.

A connection to a database from another application does not constitute it being "opened" in the sense of the Access Application which is what runs the autoexec macro.

@TimWilliams Not a problem, just a question for understanding.  Trying to understand when this runs.

@BartMcEndree So connection through a DSN to pull data from a query does NOT trigger an autoexec macro?  Will autoexec run if its opened via login script or batch file?  I don't know if that's happening, I'm just trying to gather possible causes for that being run.

The Autoexec will run if the MDB is opened via a login script or batch file. The trick is the MSAccess application must run and open the MDB to trigger the autoexec. Other applications via DNS only see a small part of the MDB containing the data.

These situations will trigger autoexec:

Opening the .mdb directly
Login script that opens Access
Batch file that opens Access

The trick is the MSAccess application must run and open the MDB to trigger the autoexec.
A connection from another application through a DSN to pull data from a query within an MDB does NOT trigger an autoexec macro.
